# Beumons touchscreen not working

Tags: display, raspberry-pi, touchscreen

First time posting here hope i'll do everything right

Just got a Beumons screen from Amazon (10.1'' Raspberry Pi screen Touchscreen Monitor 1280X800 USB HDMI, etc.). It's a touchscreen but when I activate it, the touch acts on my main screen, not my Beumons screen. I'm on Windows 10.

Any ideas ?

Comment: Are the drivers installed? does it come with a control panel that you can configure how things work?

Comment: Seems like it's an Amazon-only brand, no website, and nothing in the packaging. In the comments everybody use the screen for Rasperry Pi and not as an additonal screen, so no help either. I'm french and the description of the article is a really really bad english translation, hard to understand details.